# React Native image source not showing up

Tags: image, react-native, uri

I am trying to retrieve image data for an `<Image>` component in `React Native`.

The problem is the `API` I'm getting data from sometimes doesn't have an image source. So I have this code to check if the `source.uri` is not empty and if it is the image will be replaced by one I have saved in the project. The problem is that when the `source.uri` is null my image doesn't appear and instead there's a black space.

```js
import noImage from '../assets/noImage.jpg'
render()
{
    return (
        <Image
            style={{ width: SCREEN_WIDTH / 3, height: 13 }}
            borderRadius="10"
            resizeMode="stretch"
            source={item.restaurant.thumb ? { uri: item.restaurant.thumb } : { noImage }} />
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably try this.

```
render(){
    return(
        <Image style={{width:SCREEN_WIDTH/3, height:130}} borderRadius="10" resizeMode="stretch" source={item.restaurant.thumb ? {uri: item.restaurant.thumb} : require('../assets/noImage.jpg')}}/>
)}
```

+`require('../assets/noImage.jpg')`

-`import noImage from '../assets/noImage.jpg'`

-`{noImage}`

Answer (score 0):

I guess your "noImage" is not a web link, so you need to use `require`

```
source={item.restaurant.thumb ? {uri: item.restaurant.thumb} : require('path/noImage.png'})}
```